# Submit button is not working in spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

File jsp

```
<form:form action="saveProduct" method="POST" modelAttribute="product">
    <input type = "submit" name = "action1" value="Save"/>
</form:form>
```

File Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "action1")
public ModelAndView saveProduct(HttpServletRequest request,@ModelAttribute("product") Products product){
    if(product.getIdPro() == 0){
        proService.addPro(product);
    } else {
        proService.updatePro(product);
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/pro");
}
```

This is my jsp file and my controller. I use to extra `<table/>` tag, some another `<input/>` tag in `<form/>` tag. I tried to use `<form:input>` tag but not positive. I cannot execute submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok, except of spaces after tag attributes (that is not valid).
Try to remove thoose:

```
<input type="submit" name="action1" value="Save"/>
```